# How to terminate a loop once a specific action is complete?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and I've been trying to make a very simple game. It has some resemblance with the cricket game. Basically, the user gets to choose to bat or bowl first, and after he does so, if he chooses to bat, the computer bowls and vice-versa. Once the user has made his choice, he gets to type in an integer number between 0 and 6 and the computer chooses one too at random. If the computer's number matches the user's choice, then the one who is batting is out, then the other person bats and the first person bowls.the score is counted and the one with the greater score wins. I have a made close to this but I have an issue.

Once the batsman becomes out, the next batsman has to cross the score of the previous one to win. But in my code, the next batsman continues to bat even after having crossed the score of the previous batsman till the previous batsman (now a bowler), makes the nest batsman out.

I want a method to end the game once the second batsman crosses the score of the first.

Here's me code so far:

```
import random

def comp_bat():
    print('You are bowling')
    s=0
    comp_choice=0
    user_choice=1
    while comp_choice!= user_choice:
        user_choice=int(input('bowl: '))
        comp_choice=random.randint(0,6)
        if comp_choice==0 and user_choice!=comp_choice:
            s+=user_choice
            print('bat: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
        elif user_choice>6:
            print('Bowl numbers between 0 and 6')
        elif user_choice<0:
            print('Bowl numbers between 0 and 6')
        elif user_choice!=comp_choice:
            s+=comp_choice
            print('bat: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
        elif user_choice==comp_choice:
            print('bat: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
    print("The computer's score is:- ", s)
    return s

def user_bat():
    print('You are batting')
    s=0
    comp_choice=0
    user_choice=1
    while comp_choice!= user_choice:
        comp_choice=random.randint(0,6)
        user_choice=int(input('bat: '))
        if user_choice==0 and user_choice!=comp_choice:
            s+=comp_choice
            print('bowl: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
        elif user_choice>6:
            print('Bat numbers between 0 and 6')
        elif user_choice<0:
            print('Bat numbers between 0 and 6')
        elif user_choice!=comp_choice:
            s+=user_choice
            print('bowl: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
        elif user_choice==comp_choice:
            print('bowl: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
    print("Your score is:- ", s)
    return s

def choose_bat_bowl():
    bat=1
    bowl=2
    choice=int(input('press 1 to bat or 2 to bowl: '))
    print('')
    if choice==1:
        return bat
    elif choice==2:
        return bowl

def main():
    while True:
        if choose_bat_bowl()==1:
            x=user_bat()
            y=comp_bat()
            if x>y:
                print('You win!')
            elif x<y:
                print('You lose')
        elif choose_bat_bowl()==2:
            x=comp_bat()
            y=user_bat()
            if x>y:
                print('You lose!')
            elif x<y:
                print('You win!')


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I know this no way to code or is very basic...but please help me find a solution to terminate the loop. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a `break` statement to exit out of a loop.

Comment: While you're looking up `break`, take a look at `continue`.  The `break` ends the entire loop and moves to whatever comes next.  The `continue` ends the current iteration of the loop and moves to the next iteration.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on control-flow constructs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check current score with previous score .. Hope this will help.

```
def comp_bat(S):

    # your code

         elif user_choice!=comp_choice:
            s+=comp_choice
            print('bat: ', comp_choice)
            print('')
         elif user_choice==comp_choice:
            print('*bat: ', comp_choice)
            print('')

         if(s>S and S!=-1): # This is modified
            break

   # rest of your code

def main():
    while True:
        if choose_bat_bowl()==1:
            x=user_bat(-1)  # modified
            y=comp_bat(x)   # modified
            if x>y:
                print('You win!')
            elif x<y:
                print('You lose')
        elif choose_bat_bowl()==2:
            x=comp_bat(-1)   # modified
            y=user_bat(x)    # modified
            if x>y:
                print('You lose!')
            elif x<y:
                print('You win!')
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!! the program is running absolutely perfectly now!